# Function Overloading and Variable Number of Parameters

Tags: d

I've made and exercise on variable number of parameters:

```
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    
    enum Operation { add, subtract, multiply, divide }
    
    struct Calculation {
        Operation op;
        double first;
        double second;
    }
    
    double calculate1(in Calculation c) {
        double result;
        switch (c.op) {
            case Operation.add : {
                result = c.first+c.second;
                break;
            }
            default : {
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    double[] calculate(in Calculation[] ccs...){
        double[] result;
        foreach(c;ccs){ 
            result ~= calculate1(c);
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    writeln(calculate1(Calculation(Operation.add, 1.1, 2.2)));
    
    writeln(calculate
            ([Calculation(Operation.add, 2.1, 2.2)
             ,Calculation(Operation.add, 2.1, 2.2)
             ,Calculation(Operation.add, 2.1, 2.2)
             ,Calculation(Operation.add, 2.1, 2.2)]
             )
           );
}
```

It works ok:

> 3.3
>
> [4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3]

Then I've tried to try overload function `calculate` and change `calculate1` name to `calculate`. And it brings this errors:

> (27): Error: declaration calculate is already defined
>
> (38): Error: function calculate (const(Calculation) c) is not callable using argument types (Calculation[])

I can't get it. Is this kind of declaration brings ambiguity and compiler tries to send Calculation[] as Calculation argument? And is it possible to overload `calculate` function in this program?

EDIT: When removing `...` from line `double[] calculate(in Calculation[] ccs...){` ambiguity vanishes. Now having types `Calculation[]` and `Calculation` as arguments, error message is still the same.

EDIT2. Interesting find by  rcorre. Moving overloaded function `calculate` from `main` to upper scope this overload totally works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (27): Error: declaration calculate is already defined

Your `calculate` function is defined *inside* of `main`, but nested functions cannot be overloaded.

The compiler is refusing to create a second definition of `calculate` within `main`.

> (38): Error: function calculate (const(Calculation) c) is not callable using argument types (Calculation[])

At this point, it only has 1 definition of `calculate`, which cannot be called with a `Calculation[]`.

Try defining `calculate` outside of `main` or renaming one of the functions.

If you're really set on overloading, you could use a [typesafe variadic function](http://dlang.org/function#variadic):

```
auto calculate(Args...)(in Args ccs){
    static if (Args.length == 1) {
        // single arg, return a double
        auto c = ccs[0];
        double result;
        switch (c.op) {
            case Operation.add : 
                result = c.first+c.second;
                break;

            default : 
                break;

        }
        return result;
    }
    else {
        // multi arg, return a double[]
        double[] result;
        foreach(c;ccs){ 
            result ~= calculate(c);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The above can't be passed a `Calculation[]`, but instead would need to be called as `calculate(calculation1, calculation2, ...)`, though you could certainly extend it to handle getting an array. We need a template here because you are overloading the return type (one call may return a `double`, another returns a `double[]`).

Comment: Edited: I was wrong about the overload being invalid. That is a (surprisingly?) valid overload so long as it is not declared _inside_ another function (in this case, `main`)

Comment: Indeed. It's valid overload. Will remove my answer.